# how to tell If Device on WLAN are using internet?

Tags: automation, wifi, home-automation

So I am trying to create an automaton which will stop the music which is playing once I am asleep. Say my laptop is playing some music and say I am using my mobile I do not want the music to stop on my laptop from playing, till I fall asleep.
So say I go to bed, my phone and laptop will be connected to wifi but then they wont be accessing the internet so i want to create a automation which will stop the music when laptop and mobile are not using internet for some specific time.